# Switch the shipping rate dynamically in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I'm planning a new Shopify project, and the site requires a different shipping cost depending on the postal area of a postcode (e.g. SE1, N7). The plan was to manually add different shipping options inside of Shopify, then AJAX GET /cart/shipping_rates.json, and manually filter to the correct shipping rate by matching the name to postal area.

But my question is -- is there any way to carry over this shipping method to the Checkout as a selected option, and hide the Shipping Method drop-down from the checkout to prevent them choosing a different the shipping cost?

... Or, ideally, is there a way for me to directly override shipping costs through the API?

Comment: It would appear it's possible to hook their API for this, as I've seen a few forum threads where people have loosely spoken about doing this. I'm investigating this myself as I need to do some workarounds and will report back if I find anything.

Comment: any results? we would like to see available shipping methods for an order as well

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any onboard functionality, which can facilitate this.

But there is a quite hacky workaround, that I use to filter the shipping rates in the checkout page.

Through the "Additional Google Analytics Javascript" field you can sneak a JS on every page of the shop, including the checkout. Here you can basically manipulate the shipping rates as you like.

In your case, the code must be aware of the shipping_address zip code. You can try to set a cookie on the first checkout page and then read the same cookie on the second.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn’t possible with Shopify’s existing checkout.